# eclipse rcp standalone view--how to show hidden titles at runtime

Tags: view, show-hide, rcp, titlebar

Using RCP is it possible to show titles of a standalone view at runtime?

We have 4 stabdalone views in a page, arranged as 4 quadrants, with hidden titlebar.
On a button click, we want to show the hidden titles of all those views, so that we can move & close them as required.

Do we have any api to enable those titles? If not,how possibly can we get the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

As of now I think it is not possible to show/hide the views title at runtime:

[[RCP] [ViewMgmt] Ability to show/hide view title programmatically](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=5684)

---

But maybe you can find some workaround with the help of the following bug:

[[Presentations] Stand alone view gets title bar](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=75425)

> The stand alone view is defined to have no title bar and when the
>   perspective comes up it indeed has no title bar. However, there seems to be a very small area between the top of the view and the editor area above it that if you click and drag the mouse upward a title bar will appear.